# Memory leak detection in C/C++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

Can heap memory leaks detection be built in a C/C++ compiler? For example, in it's simplest form, during semantic analysis it would simply count allocated memory segments (with `new`/`malloc` or whatever) and `delete`/`free` calls for each one. Then give a compile-time warning about it.

Comment: IIRC there are some libraries available doing so, `malloc()`/`free()` are  weak bound functions in most ABI libs, so they can be replaced with your own version, or one coming from another library.

Comment: you've some static analysis tools such as `splint` that do so... but there are cases that you can only (easily) determine a memory leak at runtime (in that case, you may want to check `valgrind`)

Comment: Perfect garbage collection (=leak detection) in C++ is equivalent to the 'halting problem', thus can't be solved in general. That said, there are rules to keep, there are detectable hotspots you should check for. If it's new code, try using only managed ptrs and never, ever have a loop w/o `weak_ptr`. If it's old code, profile. If you have write access to the code, you might do interesting things like register instances to a global array in constructors and remove in destructor. In many cases, an additional base class is sufficient for this.

Comment: based on the title, I expected you were going to say you ran `gcc` through `valgrind` and found memory leaks or something

Answer (score 1):

See the C++ Core Guidelines which is a tool that parses the code to find deviations from the GSL standard.  This standard has statically enforceable coding rules that preclude the possibility of Memory Leaks.

https://isocpp.org/blog/2015/09/bjarne-stroustrup-announces-cpp-core-guidelines

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably you can try to make it, but you should take an account of the following things:

- You should build your application in the whole program mode (in other cases you can catch only very trivial things).
- You should make a very complex data flow analysis for pointers - just imagine that you allocated memory for some object and than assigned this pointer to another. And you free only one of them in any place of a program. Or you can put this pointer into some container.
- There can be hundreds thousands of pointers in a big application. So the analysis need a lot of memory and time. Much more than a user wants to spend.
- If you make quite a cheap and quick analysis it will be inaccurate. So you will have to print a lot of false-positive warnings or only exact warnings but for most simple things

So as a an academic research that probably will be very interesting but in real live I doubt it is possible to make such analysis of satisfying quality.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are the clang (LLVM) [sanitizers](https://github.com/google/sanitizers). They're not compile-time, but add runtime instrumentation to the emitted program.

In general, it's not possible to do a good job entirely statically, for code whose behaviour depends on inputs. Standalone static analysis tools have some heuristics for tracing various code paths, which is already sort-of dynamic-ish.

Just instrumenting the code and running it (or emulating like valgrind) is conceptually simpler, although of course it does slow down execution.

Answer (score 0):

Our [CheckPointer](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety/) tool instruments MS or GCC C programs to find a wide variety of pointer management errors that occur at runtime.

It detects dangling pointers, pointers that step outside the language-defined memory region for which they originated, including pointers to areas inside the stack (these are issues that Valgrind cannot find because it believes the entire stack is a valid place for a pointer to reference).   It also handles thread-local storage.

It reports an error at the earliest time that such an error could be reported, which makes finding the cause considerably simpler.

At the end of a run, it produces a list of allocated but not freed blocks of storage to help track down memory leaks.